# How to change and set Rcpp compile arguments

Tags: c++, r, c++11, rcpp

I created a new `Rcpp` package (by using RStudio). This package contains a C++ function that is compiled by using the following compiler options:

> clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG 
>   -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rcpp/include"
>   -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o

I would like to change/set these arguments, for example remove `-g`, add `-std=c++11` and change the argument `-O2` to `-O3`. Also, it would be better to have the possibility to specify these changes once (for the package).

Comment: Not an Rcpp question (but a generic R package compilation question) and answered previously on several occassions.  Use `src/Makevars` or `~/.R/Makevars`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working off [Writing R Extension, Section 1.2](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Configure-and-cleanup), it seems like you should be able to handle this with a couple of shell scripts. As a minimal example, (working on a Linux machine), I created a basic package from `Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton`, and put the following two files in the project root directory:

**configure**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d "~/.R" ]; then
  mkdir ~/.R; touch ~/.R/Makevars
  echo "CXXFLAGS= -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -mtune=core2" > ~/.R/Makevars
elif [ ! -e "~/.R/Makevars" ]; then
  touch ~/.R/Makevars
  echo "CXXFLAGS= -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -mtune=core2" > ~/.R/Makevars
else
  mv ~/.R/Makevars ~/.R/Makevars.bak_CustomConfig
  echo "CXXFLAGS= -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -mtune=core2" > ~/.R/Makevars
fi
```

---

**cleanup**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e "~/.R/Makevars.bak_CustomConfig" ]; then
  mv -f ~/.R/Makevars.bak_CustomConfig ~/.R/Makevars
fi
```

---

and then made them executable (`chmod 777 path/to/project/root/configure` and `chmod 777 path/to/project/root/cleanup`). 
When I ran Build and Reload I got (excerpt):

```
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  
-I/usr/local/include 
-I"/home/nr07/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include"  
-fpic  -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -mtune=core2
-c rcpp_hello.cpp -o rcpp_hello.o

g++ -m64 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib 
-Wl,-z,relro -o CustomConfig.so RcppExports.o rcpp_hello.o 
-L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
```

which overrides the R Makevars defaults, and uses the correct options.

---

This was just a basic example, so you probably would want to take it a couple steps further, depending on your goals:

1. Adapt the scripts for different platforms (e.g. Unix/Linux vs Windows/Windows 64-bit), which is touched on in the linked article I believe.
2. Ensure that setting the permissions of the file from your machine is sufficient to for these files to be executed on a different computer (I think it will work, but I'm not completely positive).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @nrussell and answered my question of 2 days searching! These solutions are an **essential** addition to the `Rcpp` vignettes which have a high learning curve. To add to your instructions I did the build by:

1. Being in an existing R project in RStudio, else do menu *File>New project*.
2. *Build > Configure Build Tools > Choose 'package'* and point to the package
   folder you've created previously i.e. `Rcpp.package.skeleton(name ="yourRpackageName",cpp_files = "yoursourcefile.cpp")`
3. Then find the *Build* tab on the top-right pane and choose *Install and Restart*
4. Run `sourceCpp`, e.g. `sourceCpp(file ="anRpackage/src/rcpp_hello_world.cpp")`. To check it has compiled with the new instructions go to the bottom-right pane and click on the *Source Cpp* tab.
5. Then the example function `rcpp_hello_world()` will work.